# Handling duplicates in VisualForce page: standard code does not work

Tags: apex, visualforce, duplicate-management

I want to handle duplicates in my custom VF page, by detecting an error after an insert action, presenting the duplicates, and having the user choose one of these or create a duplicate.

Salesforce has sample code that promises to handle precisely such a scenario: [DuplicateResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm)
Unfortunately, that doesn't work (any more?). The error that is returned by the insert method is not a DuplicateError, but an ordinary error, with status code UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION. The human readable error is along the lines of "You are trying to create a duplicate record. You are advised to use an existing record".
I nevertheless tried casting the returned error (against better judgement) to a DuplicateError, but that results in a casting error.

I have experimented with different settings for the second parameter of the insert, but so far the results have always been the same.

Anyone who has had any success with this?

My code (the relevant part of it):

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = false;
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;
//Database.SaveResult saveResult = Database.insert(newContact, dml);
Database.SaveResult saveResult = Database.insert(newContact, false);

if (! saveResult.isSuccess()) {
    for (Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors()) {
        if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
            Database.DuplicateError duplicateError = (Database.DuplicateError)error;
            Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = duplicateError.getDuplicateResult();

            // ...
        }
        else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error: ' + error.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post MVR code here?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have just posted it.

Comment: Do your results vary as you change the API version the class works against?

Comment: @KeithC That's it! Thanks, man! Never thought of that. Changed version 30.0 (old) into 38.0. Recompile. Run. Works! Now I see a list of duplicate records. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keith C had the answer. The only thing that was wrong with my code was the version. It was 30.0, I changed it into 38.0. Recompile, run, and it all worked!

As per Adrian Larson's request: the oldest version for which this works is 31.0. And yes, I double checked, 30.0 is the newest version for which this doesn't work.

I have 4 years of Apex programming experience, but until now I had never encountered a problem that could be fixed by just updating the code version.

Comment: You should run back through older versions and share the oldest version that *does* work, if you have the time.